# throw new Error('SASL: SCRAM-SERVER-FIRST-MESSAGE: client password must be a string'

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

I try to connect my database to express, but I've this message.. on PostgreSQL

```
 throw new Error('SASL: SCRAM-SERVER-FIRST-MESSAGE: client password must be a string'
```

if somebody had fix the same problem ;)

Comment: Welcome to SO, you might want to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve in order for people to be able to help you :)

Comment: Cross check to also make sure PG password isn't an empty string

Answer (score 2):

when you installed Postgresql did you set the password for Postgres user? Because I had this same issue and I solved it by doing this silly but apparently important step when you installed Postgres.
run the shell and then use the command \password.

Then should put this same password in the code you use to connect the database with express.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error message come up when I tried to connect my website running locally to my database running locally.

I was able to connect my local website to my live database. And my live website worked properly with my live database too.

But I couldn't connect my local website (or Postman) to my local database.

However, I just received help from a friend to fix this. I added this line to the top of my pool.js file:

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv/config';
```

The problem was that it wasn't accessing the environment variables from the pool.js file. Although, my friend said a better solution would be to add the 'dotenv/config' to a script in the package.json file, but he wasn't sure what the proper syntax was for that, so I'm going to try to find that out next.

Answer (score 0):

It could be password value undefined/null. If you put the password inside .env file, make sure to config it. In my program when the password value was undefined, it logged this error.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

The syntax is

```
nodemon -r dotenv/config src/server.js
```